# Python: FFT Data analysis, strange results

Tags: python, fft

I'm trying to do frequency analysis to the following [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7um2WC4G6FFazF1eXJHRVNqVFU):

Using the following code (data point for every minute):

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
df3 = pd.read_csv('Pressure - Dates by Minute.csv', sep=",", skiprows=0)
df3['Pressure FFT'] = df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean'] - df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean'].mean()
Pressure = df3['Pressure FFT']
frate = 1/60
Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(Pfft), 60)
plt.plot(freqs, Pfft)
plt.show()
```

But the results are:

[image]

Which is very strange.

Using sptool in MATLAB I got:

[image]

Which is totally different, but still strange.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the Python code ?

Eventually I want to find the different frequencies of the data.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand Numpy correctly, you're doing the lowest-level FFT algorithm, which generates a series of N complex numbers for an input of N. When doing an FFT of a real (not imaginary or complex) data signal, the resulting FFT is symmetric, so you normally fold the symmetric halves together and take the magnitude of each complex number. The [NumPy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft) has a little bit more information.

Comment: Your MATLAB plot looks like [frequency leakage from a rectangular window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Rectangular_window), so applying a windowing function might help (unless it's just a mistake in how you used MATLAB; I'm not familiar with it). Most of my experience with FFT is in the field of vibration analysis, so I don't know to what degree the techniques translate to what you're trying to do.

Comment: please define strange. First plot has a linear vertical axis, with positive and negative frequencies. The second plot has log vertical axis, with only positive frequency. It is very hard to say if there is anything wrong at all!